# how to get last inserted rows with repeated values in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables in my db with the following fields:

- gps (gps_id, serial_number)
- client (client_id,name)
- client_gps(client_id, gps_id)
- person_gps(gps_id, date1, date2)

I need to display all the serial numbers of gps devices from a selected client. The "person_gps" table can have repeated "gps_id" records.

Like this,

```
gps_id++++date1++++++++date2
===================================
110   ----10/05/99----05/05/05
110   ----03/02/06----NULL
112   ----03/02/04----04/02/04
112   ----05/09/04----06/08/08
113   ----09/09/09----10/03/10
```

And I need to check that "date2" from the last record of each gps_id is not null. So, on this example ONLY serial_number from gps with the id=112  and id=113 should be displayed.

What is the best way to do this? All of this should be created on a stored procedure, so as I said before, client_id is a given parameter (@client).

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

TIA

Comment: If date2 is NULL, how do you know it's the 'last' record? Do you mean that you want all gps_id values where there is no NULL value in date2 in any row for that gps_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from person_gps a
INNER JOIN client_gps b ON a.gps_id = b.gps_id
INNER JOIN gps c on a.gps_id = c.gps_id
WHERE b.client_id = @client_id and NOT EXISTS (select 1 from person_gps
where x a.gps_id = x.gps_id and x.date2 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY gps_id 
                     ORDER BY date2 DESC) AS RowNbr,
        person_gps.*
    FROM
        person_gps  
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    gps
    JOIN CTE
        ON gps.gps_id=CTE.gps_id
        AND CTE.RowNbr=1
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            client_gps
        WHERE
            client_gps.gps_id=gps.gps_id
            AND client_gps.client_id=2--Limit on some clientid
    )
```

Comment: The results can be obtained without a cursor.

Comment: That is NOT a cursor. Look at the code before down voting. If you do not understand then ask

Comment: My apologies, I've never seen or used select over before and it looked very much like cursor logic to at first glance. However, the desired result set can be obtained using a much simpler query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct g.serial_number
FROM person_gps pg, client_gps cg, gps g
WHERE cg.client_id = $INPUT
AND pg.gps_id = cg.gps_id
AND g.gps_id = cp.gps_id
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
               FROM person_gps
               WHERE gps_id = cg.gps_id
               AND date2 IS NULL)
ORDER BY gps_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers everybody. But this is just what I needed.

Comment: @HeinserDiaz i answered this first, Justin previous answer was not correct, he corrected after i posted this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a select statement.

First, think about what rows you want to select.  You can use row_number() to get the last row and then check that date2 is correct.  Then, join these back to the original records to pull the ones you want:

```
select *
from person_gsp pg join
     (select pg.gp_id
      from (select pg.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by gps_id order by date1 desc) as seqnum
            from person_gps pg
           ) pg
      where seqnum = 1 and date2 is not null
     ) ids
     on pg.gp_id ids.gp_id
```